# C++ - Get "id" of class's variable from enum class

Tags: c++, class, variables, enums

If I have code:

```
class A {
public:
    int x;
    enum class nums {
        Ab = 0,
        Bc,
        Cd,
        De,
        Ef
    };
    A() { this->x = 0; }
}Avar [5];
```

Is somehow possible to use `enum nums` numbers as "id" for class's variable `Avar[]`, so I don't need to converting to `int` with `static_cast<>` or `int()`?

```
if (Avar[static_cast<int>(A::nums::Cd)].x == 10) {
```

Something like `Avar[A::nums::Cd].x` ?

Comment: @dxiv Yes. Can be, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An enum class (aka scoped enumeration) is not implicitly convertible to an integer and cannot thus be used as an index of an array without a cast. You can use a plain enum instead of an enum class. Unlike enum classes, an enum is implicitly convertible to an integer and can therefore be used as an index of an array.

P.S. Don't use a magic number for the size of the array. Use an extra enum value that will have the size:

```
    enum nums {
        Ab = 0,
        Bc,
        Cd,
        De,
        Ef,
        nums_count,
    };
...
}Avar [A::nums_count];
```